# Binding StartIO3.1.jar to Xamarin Android

Tags: java, android, xamarin.android, printers, stario-sdk

Following the instruction on 
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-a-jar/

I hit the following problem.

> /Projects/Printer/Printer/obj/Release/generated/src/Com.Starmicronics.Stario.ConnectBlueBluetoothManager.cs(112,112): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name `IStarBluetoothManager' does not exist in the namespace`Com.Starmicronics.Stario'. Are you missing an assembly reference? (CS0234) (Printer)

How should I create Jar binding used for Xamarin Android

Comment: Stephen have the same issue. Have you solved yours?